# Embedding code using API of GPL library in tutorial website

Tags: licensing, gpl, gpl-2

I want to make a commercial tutorial website that will teach people to use GPL-licensed R packages in a series of articles.

The website will not execute the code, but will show people the output of the GPL code.

I could teach people to use [ggplot2](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/) (a graphing package that is GPL v2) by showing the code and [the output](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/figures/README-example-1.png) from ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) + 
  geom_point()
```

Would these code snippets also need to be licensed under GPL given the package is GPL as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether using a library creates a derivative work is not entirely clear. Opinions range across:

- What no, that's silly!
- The running software is a derivative work because it includes the GPL-covered software, but your source code isn't.
- Your source code is a derivative work because it uses GPL-covered APIs (is designed to require that GPL-covered work).

The safest approach is to assume that your snippets might indeed be derivative of the GPL library. Then:

- If the snippets are short or trivial, they may not be eligible for copyright protection and you don't have to do anything.
- Otherwise, they should be available under the GPL. This does not necessarily mean that you have to offer them under the GPL; any compatible license such as MIT or CC0 would work as well.

I would satisfy this requirement by either linking to a complete script from which your snippets are taken and clearly offering that script under a GPL-compatible license, or by putting a license dedication for those snippets at the end of the blog post.

Note that the entire R ecosystem depends on GPLv2-covered software, so this analysis is likely not unique to that package in question.

Output of GPLv2 covered software is NOT subject to the GPL (see the [GPL FAQ](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#WhatCaseIsOutputGPL)). You can show plots etc. without any restrictions or attribution requirements.